# Python mysql - cursor.close() db.close()

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

I am opening, accessing, writing, etc, to a database within various classes and threads in my application. I have one database `self.run_params["db"]` which I am using to access throughout my application.

Question 1: Should I be closing the cursor each time after each individual access?

Question 2: My Application runs constantly and accesses the database at various different points, so should I close the database after each access, or only close the database on exit of the application?

```
import MySQLdb
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

self.run_params = {}
self.run_params["databaseName"] = "transporterDatabase"
self.run_params["tableName"] = "transporterTable"

## Create databse if not already exist ##
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="password")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + self.run_params["databaseName"])
db.close()

## Create table if not already exist ##
self.run_params["db"] = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="password",
                     db=self.run_params["databaseName"])

cur = self.run_params["db"].cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + self.run_params["tableName"] + "(jobID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(jobID), location VARCHAR(5000), mode VARCHAR(50), process VARCHAR(10), status VARCHAR(30), title VARCHAR(500), vendorID VARCHAR(100), provider VARCHAR(100), packageType VARCHAR(50), assetUpdate VARCHAR(5), folderSubmission VARCHAR(5), submitTime VARCHAR(50), priority VARCHAR(5));")
cur.close()

######################

## Use database info ##
cur = self.params["db"].cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s order by %s" % (self.params["tableName"], 'priority'))                 

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    jobID = row[0]
    indir1 = row[1]
    runningMode = row[2]
    process = row[3]
    status = row[4]
    title = row[5]
    vendorID = row[6]
    provider = row[7]
    packageType = row[8]
    assetUpdate = row[9]
    folderSubmission = row[10]

cur.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be closing the cursor each time after each individual access?

It's generally not necessary to close the `MySQLdb` cursor; it is an object in Python that behaves like a cursor, but is not implemented or managed by the MySQL server. You may prefer to close the cursor, and there's nothing wrong with doing so; perhaps you feel it makes your code easier to understand or there are cases when you want to catch and handle an error related to attempts to use a cursor that should not be available. However, it's not something you need to worry much about when using the `MySQLdb` module.

> My Application runs constantly and accesses the database at various different points, so should I close the database after each access, or only close the database on exit of the application?

Again, this depends on your specific needs and preferences. If you are using [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html), these will be available only while the connection in which they were defined remains open. If you are having issues with the connection timing out, it might be more convenient for you to only keep the connection open during periods of high activity. Generally speaking, there's nothing wrong with leaving a connection open indefinitely if you really need continuous, frequent access.

As far as what constitutes "continuous, frequent access," that is probably a matter of whether or not you're having problems with the server timing out. I have a process that needs server access more frequently than once each second, which has been running on a single open connection for the better part of a week; I would call this "continuous, frequent access."

Answer (score -1):

You can create a single database object for accessing database and use locking mechanism (such as Semaphore or RLock) for synchronized access to this object.

Comment: You can have a look at following links:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html and http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Comment: I don't think I want to lock and synchronise access to the database as, different threads are accessing the database independently of each other. I just need to know about closing the curser and database correctly after each occurrence.